# Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate:pom:3.3.2.GA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

In my pom.xml of my spring application I am getting this error when I hover on it to see the issue

```
Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate:pom:3.3.2.GA
```

this is the xml declaration

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: artifact ID needs to be hibernate-core perhaps? http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.2.GA

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```